# Multiplication within payload

Tags: javascript

I am working on a product, and I am trying to create a payload. I need `total` to be equal to `totalPrice`*`taxRate`. I tried doing this by:

`total: selectedQuantities.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value * c.price, 0).reduce((m, n) => m * n.taxRate)`

and by:

`total: selectedQuantities.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value * c.price, 0) * devolucionItems.taxRate`

Neither of these worked, and I really appreciate any help or advice with this, thank you!

Full Payload:

````
const returnPayload = {
            ...devolucionItems,
            qty: totalQuantity,
            seller: devolucionItems.user._id,
            orderItems: devolucionItems.orderItems.map((item) => {
                const result = selectedQuantities.find((selectedItem) => selectedItem.id === item._id);
                return { ...item, qty: result.value, price: +result.price * +result.value, tax: result.tax};
            }),
            itemsPrice: selectedQuantities.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price, 0),
            totalPrice: selectedQuantities.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value * c.price, 0),
            taxRate: devolucionItems.taxRate,
            total: selectedQuantities.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value * c.price, 0).reduce((m, n) => m * n.taxRate),
        };```
````

Comment: Your second attempt seems like it should work, assuming each item in `selectedQuantities` has a `value` and a `price`. (Though, I would assign that value to a variable first, then pass it into both `totalPrice` and the `total` calculation, to avoid doing the reduce twice)

Comment: Also, are you seeing any errors when you run it, what exactly does "Neither of these worked" mean in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it means that it is not working.
In your calculation 2nd, reduce will not work.

I would suggest giving more context like the input object and what you get and what you expected etc. I was trying to create the context you can check below which is working fine as expected.

```js
const devolucionItems = { taxRate:10 }

const selectedQuantities = [
    {value: 1, price: 100},
    {value: 1, price: 100},
    {value: 1, price: 100},
]

const returnPayload = {
            ...devolucionItems,
            itemsPrice: selectedQuantities.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price, 0),
            totalPrice: selectedQuantities.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value * c.price, 0),
            taxRate: devolucionItems.taxRate,
            total: selectedQuantities.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value * c.price, 0) * (devolucionItems.taxRate / 100),
        };

console.log(returnPayload);
```

Output:

```
{taxRate: 10, itemsPrice: 300, totalPrice: 300, total: 30}
```

10 % of 300 = 30